# Passing a variable to a path

Tags: node.js, variables, path

I have the following code:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public/')));
```

After the Backslash (`public/"here"`) I want to pass a variable. So depending on the value of the variable it should open a different subfolder of public.

I tried this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public/'+variable+')));
```

But I just get an error

Comment: Which is the error?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: what is the end result you're trying to achieve? doesn't look *regular* thing to have conditional `static` folder

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment but you have a syntax error.

You should have have

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public/'+ variable)));
```

instead of

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public/'+variable+')));
```